# How to send data to ActiveAdmin in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a rate field form that's needs to be moderated by an admin and if everything's okay, show it on a page. So how can I send this form's data straight to the ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to create a normal controller for that, wich stores the data and then ActiveAdmin shows up the data to the moderator.

If you really want to do that:

1. Create a separate Namespace for the Form, name it `form-admin` (Other wise you will get a security problem or more).
2. Configure this Namespace to not use devise.
3. Turn of CSRF token `controller do; protect_from_forgery :except => :create; end`
4. Send the form to `/form-admin/your-modelname` as post.
5. If you need to know how the form looks like, copy it from `/form-admin/your-modelname/new`